# How to see the Firebase Event Analytics with custom parameters in CSV report?

Tags: firebase, mobile, metrics, firebase-analytics

We've developed a Flutter mobile App and we've firebase account.

For our App we need to add Firebase analytics for the App Events such as button clicks.

We've integrated the Analytics SDK in the Mobile App and created an Events with custom parameters and we can see the count of Events and Users counts in the Firebase Excel/CSV report  but we're unable to see the custom parameters in the report.

Our requirement is to see the  Events analytics reports with the custom parameters in CSV report without linking the Bigquery. Please advise with the steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For seeing parameters in firebase dashboard as well as in csv report first check if the event is triggered in DebugView and then you need to define some custom definitions.

[image]

In new custom definition choose from your previously given parameters. Normally it takes several hours to get the parameters in event parameter.

[image]

The parameter will be shown in Dashboard as event parameter after 24 hours and you can download it as CSV/pdf

[image]

Also for analyze data you can use Google Data Studio which imports your data from analytics and helps to generate different types of graphical reports according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Custom parameters are included in the [download as a CSV report](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7521152?hl=en). You can actually replicate this using the [Firebase demo project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7157552?hl=en). Go to Analytics > Events > click on level_complete event. In the level_complete page, you will see the level_name parameter card and its values. When you download this as CSV, you can see the list of level_name values in the file with metrics such as the number of times it has been logged and number of users who logged it.

Please note that when you register custom parameters, a data card for each parameter is added to the related event-detail report. However, it may take up to 24 hours for the data card to appear. During this 24-hour period, you may see (not set) appear as a parameter value. Once that initial 24-hour period has passed, you will see the expected parameter values from that point forward. See this [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en) for your reference.